# What is it called when the "one" of a phrase, or 8-count is accented?

Tags: terminology

The verses of the song Whatchugot by Caro Emerald have a **very obvious** bop every 8 beats.

I'd like to find other pop songs that highlight the 1 of each 8 count, or *even better* the 1 of each 32-count phrase, but I don't know the terminology to describe what I'm looking for to Google.

Is there a term for this?

Comment: If you count this as 1&2&3&4&, the very obvious bop is on the first beat of every bar.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are thinking of "the one" or "on the one" which I know as associated with James Brown.

You can look it up in lots of places, but this BBC video *[James Brown's Rhythm Of The One](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wUVs9JAI3jg)* is a nice source.

BTW, you might be off with the count of 8 and counting eighth notes instead of quarter note beats. At least with "the one" it's an accent on beat one of a bar of four beats.

Answer (score 0):

*Boogie-woogie* is a style often called "eight to the bar." The song sounds to me like a hybrid of boogie-woogie superimposed over a 4/4 rock backbeat.

Boogie-woogie is often swung, so to be more precise I'd this a *straight boogie*.

Answer (score 0):

There may be other terms for this in popular music, but one related technical term in music theory is *hypermeter*, where measures are grouped together into larger units, so you might feel a sense of a "downbeat" every 2 bars or 4 bars or 8 bars or whatever.  In the song you mention, there is a "bop" on each hypermetric downbeat.

Otherwise in pop music, there is also the notion of a "groove," which often tends to cycle and repeat every X number of beats or measures.  (However, the term "groove" can also mean a lot of things, from the "feel"/style of a piece to a cyclic rhythmic pattern.)  Some people also just call these a "cycle" of beats.

There's probably some other term I'm forgetting but these are a few that are related to the pattern you're noticing.